# Backlinking through Javascript

Tags: javascript, seo

What possible ways are there for backlinking through javascript based content?  I know the crawler doesn't execute the scripts, but is there any other way possible?

Regards,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured a much easier way to do this.  Simply setting up the link in the noscript will redirect back to your site.

I.e.

blahScript;Sponsored by Blah

Answer (score 1):

Google publishes excellent guidelines on making AJAX applications crawlable at:

- http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/

Pretty much everything you need to know there, for Google's crawler anyway.

Comment: Pretty helpful information.  I may have forgotten to mention though that the javascripts would exist on external sites.  So my JS based widgets won't be able to modify client's servers.